# Are record synergies multiplicative?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

Say for example I'm in one of the FF7 dungeons, and I have Cloud & Tyro in my party; and 1 FF7 weapon.

To maximize my damage; should I give it to Cloud or to Tyro?  Will Cloud's record synergy further boost the weapon synergy, or is it the same whether it's on Cloud or Tyro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record synergy is calculated separately for items and characters. There is no additional bonus for having an item with record synergy equipped on a character with record synergy. https://www.reddit.com/r/FFRecordKeeper/wiki/index/synergy has a good explanation on how record synergy is calculated for characters and items.